# Getting one row from the same value of multiple rows with multivalue spesific column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to get one row from the same value of multiple rows with multi-value specific column (in this case is `id_pengolahan`) like this?

[image: database table]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint `GROUP BY`.  `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `group_concat` function in `mysql`, you can remove `distinct` if you wan't to repeat `id_pengolahan` in your `comma` separated list.

```
select id_btp
    , id_bahan
    , id_senyawa
    , group_concat(distinct id_pengolahan           
       separator ',') as id_pengolahan
    , id_kategori
    , batas_maksimum 
from tableA 
group by id_btp
    , id_bahan
    , id_senyawa    
    , id_kategori
    , batas_maksimum
```